# How can I change any app code class after publishing the website?

Tags: asp.net, web, publish

I upload the website after publishing it, now I want to change a line of code in a class which resides in app_code folder. After changes I again publish the website and upload the new app_code.dll to replace the old one but its not working. The whole functionality of app_code is not working. Is there anybody to solve my problem? thanx in advance.

Comment: you have to rebuild it.

Comment: before publishing the website after changes i build it and the replace the old app_code.dll with new one. are you saying that I have to replace the whole uploaded website with new modified?

Comment: I said you should rebuild it and you did.  Just updating dll works but you shouldn't do it always. You might miss something.

Comment: there is a problem in my database, now its working. sorry for bothering you and thanx for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

The `App_Code` folder will parse any source files you drop in there, e.g. MyClass.vb or MyClass.cs. If you are compiling classes into a DLL, you want to put the DLL file into the `bin` folder instead.

If the classes are contained in your project and have their build action set to compile, they will automatically be compiled into the web application's DLL when you run a build, and should update every time you publish the site as a publish automatically builds the project/solution.